# Rails 4.0.0 foreign key for models

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is this wrong to have that same foreign key for two different models? It's Rails 4.0.0 app so conditions are written like that. I ask because I got some problem with blinks and can't find it.

```
  has_many :messages, :conditions => {:deleted => false, :subject_h => ''}
  has_many :messages_send, :class_name => "Message", :foreign_key => "sender_id", :conditions => ['deleted_sender = ?', false]

  has_many :blinks, :conditions => {:deleted => false, :subject_h => ''}
  has_many :blinks_send, :class_name => "Blink", :foreign_key => "sender_id", :conditions => ['deleted_sender = ?', false]
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do one of the two following things:

1 - Have one table per model (so one `blinks` table and one `messages` table).

2 - Use [Single Table Inheritance (STI)](http://eewang.github.io/blog/2013/03/12/how-and-when-to-use-single-table-inheritance-in-rails/) for each messages. You would have only one table (`senders` in your case), with a `type` field that would differentiate between a blink and a message.

For simplicity here, I would personally go for the first option, and evolve to the STI later on if still needed.

The advantage would also be that you'll be able to declare your associations like this:

```
has_many :messages
has_many :blinks
```

Comment: yee i thought about this but it's old apps and just make new model for blink

Comment: What is your table structure for this legacy app then?